# Sharepoint calendar webpart connected with filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-calendar

I have a requirement in SharePoint Online/Office365 in which following things are needed.

Calendar list with custom field "Category", type is choice (Holidays, Events, Others) Need to creates as a drop down in which above field's value should bind.The View to be used is Calendar View, I have already tried SharePoint list filter and list view webpart but only AllEvents view is supported and Calendar view is not. I strictly want to use Calendar View. Is there any way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Low tech solution:

Lets say you have 5 categories.  Make a 2 column page for each category.  Make a link list with an entry for each page.  For each page add the calendar in one column and the link list in the other.  Set the calendar view in the web part on each page to filter on category.

So each page will show all filtered events on a calendar.  And there will be a link list to get to the other views(pages).

Answer (score 0):

The following article shows how to set up filters using a "calculated column" and some HTML and Jquery to filter them.

The example uses coloured buttons for filtering but this could easily be modified to use a dropdown list instead.

[SharePoint calendar view filters](https://crm.webfletch.co.uk/posts/sharepoint-calendar-filter-resource-on-a-single-calendar-office-365)

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this article. It might be helpful.

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/reservation-of-resources-in-sharepoint-2013-and-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Thanks Ayub for the reply, I tried this but this did not fulfill my requirements.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? Thank you!